# Mostrar campos de una tabla de la base de datos en una vista - laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Buen día tengo el siguiente problema, estoy realizando un crud haciendo uso de laravel, donde introduzco mis datos y los muestro en una tabla, hasta ahí todo bien, lo que me presenta problemas es pasar los datos introducidos en mi tabla (lo que se muestra en la primera imagen) a una nueva vista y que al momento que el usuario de clic en el botón siguiente cambie al siguiente registro y así sucesivamente (imagen 2).

En mi archivo web.php definí el siguiente código para hacer la consulta y mostrar los datos, pero no considero que sea correcto.

```
Route::get(
'test',
function () {
    $data = DB::select('SELECT pregunta FROM preguntas WHERE id = 1');

    return View::make('menu_test.test')
        ->with('preguntas', $data);
});
```

Mientras que en mi vista lo llame de la siguiente forma

```
@foreach($preguntas as $pregunta)
 <li class="list-unstyled">
   <p>{{ $pregunta->pregunta }}</p>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Como podría recibir los campos de pregunta y cada respuesta para posteriormente mostrarlos en la vista (imagen 2).
Y seria posible almacenar el valor de la respuesta que el usuario seleccione en otra tabla?
De antemano gracias.

[image: Los datos que introduje en mi tabla que tienen los campos pregunta y respuestas]
[image: La vista donde quiero recibir los datos de mi tabla, para la pregunta y respuesta a, b y c]

Algunos datos extra por si son necesarios
-Laravel 10, Php 8.2, Base de datos mysql, Código de mi vista test.blade.php

```
<div class="container col-5">
    <div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Test: Test X</h5>
            <h7 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Pregunta
            </h7>
            <hr>
            <p class="card-text">
              @foreach($preguntas as $pregunta)
                <li class="list-unstyled">
                    <p>{{ $pregunta->pregunta }}</p>
                </li>
               @endforeach
            </p>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1"
                    value="option1">
                <li class="list-unstyled">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                        a. Respuesta A
                    </label>
                </li>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2"
                    value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                    b. Respuesta B
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3"
                    value="option3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                    c. Respuesta C
                </label>
            </div>
            </br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Siguiente</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```